# Can not update array field in MYSQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am working with `MYSQL` via `Sequelize` and I created a field for an `array`. I read that I could do this with `DataTypes` of `JSON` in `MYSQL` and set the default value to `[]`. I did this and I would like to update that field with `string` values. I have tried push like this:

```
category.dataValues.array_Of_food?.push('item1')

 await category.save()
```

It won't save the added item in the database. If I use the `update` method like this:

```
await category.update({array_Of_food: category.dataValues.category_name})
```

This changes the `array_of_food` field with simply a string and not an array.
How do I simply push an item into the array field if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using this code:

```
  category.update({ array_Of_food: Sequelize.fn(
        'JSON_ARRAY_APPEND',
        Sequelize.col('array_of_food'),
        '$',
            food.dataValues.food_Name
      )})
```